# Why was libgnomeui-dev removed from the Debian testing repository, while still being in sid, stable, oldstable and oldoldstable?

Tags: debian

I have a [Vim package in the openSUSE Build Service](https://build.opensuse.org/package/show/home:fusion809/vim-debian) that isn't building because for some reason Debian testing no longer has a libgnomeui-dev package, even though every other maintained Debian branch does. I'd like to ask why? I could understand it being dropped if it was redundant and was also dropped from the sid branch but it hasn't.

Comment: Looks like everything in the distro that depended on it was removed, possibly as a cleanup of old GNOME libs.

Comment: Interesting, I wouldn't suppose you'd be familiar enough with the OBS to offer me a fix for this Vim-building issue?

Comment: I have no idea what the issue might be. What I would do is try to find a workaround for the libraries dependent on libgnomeui, maybe search around for a relevant patch.

Answer (score 1):

[Old, unmaintained GNOME libraries are being removed from Buster](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2017/10/msg00299.html) (the current `testing`) and won’t be released with Debian 10. They’re still present in Sid but they all have blocking bugs to prevent their migration; `libgnomeui`’s blocking bug is [#885767](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=885767).

To build with Buster you need to remove the `libgnomeui-dev` dependency, it won’t be coming back.

Comment: Any ideas on how I remove it just for Debian testing while keeping it for build targets that do have it? Debian control files do not seem to manage conditionals as well as Red Hat spec files.

Comment: Unfortunately not, the Debian source format doesn’t deal well with build systems which target multiple distributions with the exact same source :-(. [Debian dropped `vim-gnome` entirely in favour of `vim-gtk3`](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=820239); does the GNOME support provide anything extra beyond the Gtk+3 support?